# Swift rotation gesture x and y off axis issue

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm using a rotation gesture recognizer to rotate a UIView. After I've rotated the view the x and y coordinates of the pan gesture are off their axis and I can't see why.

Here is my current gesture setup:

```
open func handleRotate(sender: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {

        sender.view?.transform = (sender.view?.transform)!.rotated(by: sender.rotation)
        sender.rotation = 0
    }
}
@objc fileprivate func handleDrag(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = sender.translation(in: self)

    sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: self)

}
```

So when I rotate the UIView the x and y panning are off (Moving up moves the uiview to the left or right depending upon the UIview's rotated state).

Thanks

Comment: try setting the anchor point of your view first before doing the rotation ... try this `view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)`
`

Comment: That didn't work @Bilal

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a lot to unpack with the code example provided, but for starters the drag handler is setting the center point of the view, which might be a hint as to why the rotation gesture is askew.

Rather than setting the transform property of the view independently in each handler, you might get the result you're looking for if you modify the existing transforms.

The SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474496/using-multiple-uigesturerecognizers-simultaneously-like-uirotationgesturerecogni/44474497#44474497) goes into a bit more depth, and might help:

[Using multiple UIGestureRecognizers simultaneously like UIRotationGestureRecognizer & UIPanGestureRecognizer in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474496/using-multiple-uigesturerecognizers-simultaneously-like-uirotationgesturerecogni/44474497#44474497)